# Record a new contribution to several contacts selected, for example, using search contacts by group

Tags: contributions, actions

is possible to record a new contribution to several contacts selected, for example, using search contacts by group?
I don't think so, but I'm surprised by it. The closer approach is import CSV data or use batch process, but the first is not the easiest way for non-tech staff and the second is not suitable for big groups of contacts.

Comment: do you mean one contribution per contact (eg 10 people each separately gave $10) or one contribution for all the contacts (eg a group of 10 people collectively gave a single donation of $100)

Comment: Your first option: (eg 10 people each separately gave $5, so the total contributed is $50)

Comment: i doubt there is an easier non-tech solution that Import Contribution or the Batch approach

Comment: actually if you were on drupal, a webform can handle up to 30 (or 31). caldera for WP may offer similar